# Is it possible to rename parent param in nested routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
  resources :client, only: [] do
    get :info
  end
```

Using above route the system will generate a route `/client/:client_id/info(.:format)`

I would like to know if it is possible to change `:client_id` to, say `:customer_id` in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :client, as: :customer, only: [] do
  get :info
end
```

will generate `/client/:customer_id/info`

**Note:** You'll have to use `customer_info_path` instead of `client_info_path`

Comment: Perfect. I forgot the `as` option.

Comment: You had me wondering for a moment when you said its not possible :)

Comment: I was lost for sometime.. too many options they don't come right top of the head when needed. :)

Comment: And I also looked through [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) which did not say `:as` option.

Comment: One more question, how can I create a path with `/client/:id/info(.:format)`?